# Edge Browser - Set Cookie with Cross Domain Request

Tags: angularjs, cookies, cors, microsoft-edge

As part of a project I'm working on, we need to send a cross domain request.
I have the following call:

```
$http({
       url: 'http://192.168.1.1/API/Login',
       method: "POST",
       data: {
            password: $scope.pass
       },
       withCredentials: true,
       cached: false,
       headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
```

When I send the request to the non-origin server, I get the following response (from Wireshark):

```
POST /API/Login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,he;q=0.3
Origin: http://myserver.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
Host: 192.168.1.1
Content-Length: 21
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"password":"1234"}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 19 Jun 2016 21:07:52 GMT
Server: Some server (UNIX)

Set-Cookie: Session=308333957
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myserver.com
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 152

{"key":"abcdefg","name":"Joe","session":"308333957"}
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome and FireFox but on Edge it has a CORS error:

```
Origin http://myserver.com not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
```

Btw, when the login credentials are wrong and the server does not return the 'Set-Cookie' it works fine!!!
Thought that by using 'withCredentials=true' I'll allow setting cookies in a cross domain request but it didn't help (on Edge only).

Any ideas?
Any chance there's a bug in Edge? I couldn't find anything open.

Thanks

Comment: with credentials tells browser to send cookies within request. Note you are looking at the POST headers...not the OPTIONS preflight which is likely where problem is

Comment: I don't see any preflight request sent before the POST request. From the documentation of withCredentials:
Note: XmlHttpRequest responses from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request, regardless of Access-Control- header values.

Comment: OK.. i may have misinterpeted withCredentials but all CORS requests will have an OPTIONS preflight. Can see them in some dev tools but not others. Install fiddler and look there. Basically it is checking headers and if they aren't right the POST won't get sent

Comment: First, Fiddler is dangerous...once you run it, it opens a local proxy which hides all CORS issues...took me some time to understand that. As for the preflight, I'm using Wireshark which captures all network traffic and not preflight is sent

Comment: Strange...is part of CORS spec to have OPTIONS preflight. Where are you actually loading page .. using IP or using `http://localhost`?

Comment: The non origin server is an IP address